# Remove custom taxonomy 'post-type' from post URL

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, urls

I want to remove custom taxonomy 'post-type' from post URLs like:

```
http://example.com/wordpress/post-type/post1
```

to

```
http://example.com/wordpress/post1
```

I have used lots of plugins and rewrote URL. But didn't get success. I can not mention real site URL.

Comment: What have you tried exactly? What is the peramlink structure set in "Settings"? Do you have any rewrites set in your [register_post_type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) function?

Comment: yes, i have set portfolio for register_post_type. and when we create a post of this post type then it will send url as /portfolio/postname. But i want only /postname . I have set post name in parmalink setting.

Comment: Could you post your `register_post_type` and (if you have) your `register_taxonomy` functions?

Comment: yes, i have tried. But using this we can change only category name to portfolio or anything else. But i am not able to remove this.